# Running C++ libraries in .NET independently

Tags: c#, c++

I have a .net application which uses C++ libraries. In the app you can run multiple jobs and each job uses C++ libraries to do some computations. The problem is, C++ objects are shared between jobs and I want to avoid it. The only way I can think of is to run each task as a separate process. Is there a better way to do it? Like running in a different scope

Comment: AppdDomain? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Matas C++ is shared between .NET appdomains, isn't it?

Comment: @Matas, I'm afraid, AppDomain does only properly isolate .NET code and is not of much help with native code. I faced such isolation problems when was dealing with COM objects.

Comment: Yeah, apparently appdomain is not an option in this case. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367079/several-appdomains-and-native-code

Comment: Stating the obvious maybe, but how about not sharing objects and instead creating one C++ object for each job?

Comment: C++ library is 3rd party

Comment: "multiple jobs" == "multiple threads"?  No, large chunks of C++ code (even small chunks) are never thread-safe.  There is no magic button you can push to make that problem disappear.  Running it in separate processes to keep them strictly isolated is a solution that tends to produce two new very hard to solve problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**, but it's not easy.

AppDomain doesn't provide isolation for native code, so you cannot use it for your aim. Each unmanaged dll is loaded once per process, not per AppDomain.

You can use WinAPI `LoadLibrary()` function to load your libraries manually multiple times. Each copy of the loaded library can be used in separate thread with a safe thread context. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jonathanswift/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-net-c/) is the description of how to call a function from dynamically loaded library. Don't forget to call `FreeLibrary()` to free resources.

Comment: But what if I don't have access to .net wrapper? Am i done?

Comment: @Zbigniew Unfortunately, yes. If your .NET wrapper contains some logic and you cannot change it or create new one, than the only way is to run such a code in a separate process.